# Deconstruct an SQL Statement in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have some legacy SQL and I want to split it up into it's constituent parts & then add more criteria, an order by clause, etc.

Are there any existing Java libraries out there that interpret SQL like this?

So I want to do something like

```
deconstructedSQL.getCriteria().add("price > 100");
```

or

```
deconstructedSQL.getOrderBy().add("price");
```

or

```
String select = deconstructedSQL.getSelect();
if ("*".equals(select))
{
    deconstructedSQL.setSelect("my_table.*");
}
```

I can use Dialects from Hibernate to add info specific to my database for paging (`setFirstResult` & `setMaxResult`), but I'd like to take it a step further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a sql parser (javacc, jparsec, antlr) to break up the string into an AST.  Once you have it in this kind of structure you can play with it as you describe and emit the modified version as a string in the end.

Comment: "SQL Parser" was the phrase that eluded me when googling this. Having a look at Zql now - http://www.gibello.com/code/zql/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to checkout the [SQL Builder](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/) library.  It is a builder pattern based library for building SQL statements.  I'm not positive if it has a deconstruction piece to it where you can give it a SQL statement and have it break it down into parts though.

Comment: That's great. Between Zql & SQL Builder, I should have my solution!

Answer (score 1):

This is a demo that illustrate how to [Deconstruct, Modify, Rebuild an SQL statement](http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/deconstruct-modify-rebuild-an-sql-statementjava-version/) with the help of a SQL Parser.

original SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_X where f > 0
```

Java code:

```
assertTrue(parser.parse() == 0);
TSelectSqlStatement select = (TSelectSqlStatement)parser.sqlstatements.get(0);
select.addWhereClause("c>1");
```

what you get is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_X where f > 0 and c>1
```

select list, group by, order clause can also be modified easily.

Answer (score 0):

The [Zsql](http://www.gibello.com/code/zql/) framework matches exactly with your description (not tested).